# Java: RGB, HSL, and subtractive color mixing

Tags: java, algorithm, colors, rgb, light

I have an application that requires me to mix two colors subtractively (as in mix them to get a result as if I has mixed two pigments). Just adding the RGB's doesn't work as RGB values operate additively, whereas pigments operate subtractively.

So what I'm trying to do is use HSL values. I convert the RGB to HSL using one of Java's Color Methods. I'm seeing colors as degrees on a wheel. Red has a hue value of 0, Green is 0.333, and Blue is 0.666. Since this is a wheel Red can also be 1, and green can also be 1.333.

So what I'm doing is averaging the hue values (as I'm mixing the "pigments" in equal ratios) along the shortest distance on the wheel. To explain, mixing blue (0.666) and red (0 or 1) would evaluate to 0.833, not 0.666. In my implementation, I account for this or at least try to, but there are some bugs...

```
public static Color addColors(Color a, Color b) {

    float[] aHSB = toHSB(a);
    float[] bHSB = toHSB(b);

    double aHue = aHSB[0];
    double bHue = bHSB[0];

    System.out.println(aHue * 360 + ", " + bHue * 360);

    double c = 0;

    if (Math.abs(Math.abs(aHue - bHue) - 0.5) < 0.01) {
        return Color.BLACK; //to account for complimentary colors
    }

    if (Math.abs(aHue - bHue) > 0.51) {
        c = 0.5;
    }

    float temp = (float) (((aHue + bHue) / 2) % 1 + c);

    Color d = new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(temp, 
                            (aHSB[1] + bHSB[1]) / 2, 
                            (aHSB[2] + bHSB[2]) / 2));


    return d;
}
```

When I mix Blue and Yellow, I get a green-ish tint. When I mix Red and Yellow, I get an orange, but when I mix orange and blue, I get a pink. I imagine there a problems with what I'm doing.

Are there better ways to mix colors given RGB values that yield results that match pigment mixing? Or am I on a (semi) right track and have just made a mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure whether `return new Color(a.getRGB() & b.getRGB());` would be a sufficient answer here...

Comment: (Note, by the way, that mixing blue and yellow should yield black. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color )